# Why User.Identity.IsAuthenticated keeps being set to true even I signed out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

There is a piece of legacy with which I have some issues.

Let's say on the same browser, I have a user who is already logged-in and another user would like to confirm his or her email for creating his or her password and hence activating his or her user account.

It turns out that the user already logged-in is not signed out when the other user is confirming his email even though, I call the two methods below:

- `await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();`
- `await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(alreadyLoggedInUser);`

The Controller Action code:

```cs
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string code, string userId)
{
    if (code == null || userId == null)
    {
        return View("TokenError");
    }

    await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();

    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("User not found");
        return View("TokenError");
    }

    var alreadyLoggedInUser= await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(alreadyLoggedInUser);

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("Set-Cookie");

    if (await CheckAccountActivationTokenAsync(user, code))
    {
        return View("CreatePasswordView", new SetPasswordViewModel());
    }

    Logger.LogInformation("Invalid token");
    return View("TokenError");
}
```

The view returned is based on a layout and in one of the partial views, there is a check to know whether the user is authenticated or not which turns out to be the case.

```
@using MySecretProject.Core.App_LocalResources
@{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account", new { Area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, null, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">@Resource.Logout</a>
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that the already logged-in user is properly signed out so that when the view for creating a password for user trying to confirm his or her email, there is no trace of the other user.

Comment: how is it posible? do you have something static? our save something about user in a cache?

Comment: Nope, no static, no user cache =/

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

in signout action.